# Specify images to act as a bullet point using CSS

Tags: html, css, styling

I have shown my code below. For some reason, It's not working.

```
<div class="blocker">
    <h3>Favorite Websites</h3>
        <ul>
        <li>Nettuts.com</li>
        <li>Webdesignerdepot</li>
        <li>SixRevisions</li>
        <li>Smashing Magazine</li>
        <li>WebdesignerWall</li>
      </ul>

      </div>

  ul{
    list-style-image: url("img/icon.png"); }
  li{
    margin: 10px;}
```

Comment: Are there any 404 errors around missing images in your javascript console? Thats always the first thing I check when an image I'm using with CSS doesn't display.

Comment: Ok, I figured that out. It seems those icon images are having an issue. But, the paths are correct.

Comment: View -> Developer tools on a Mac. Probably something similar on windows, I don't remember off the top of my head for windows.

Comment: This is the path I should have /WebDesign/img/icon.jpg. But, this is what the console show me >> /WebDesign/css/img/icon.jpg. I have no idea how the css folder got in there. My icon is in the img folder. I created an img folder in there and the list-icon shows up.

Comment: thats because you are using a relative path in your css stylesheet. you can use an absolute path `'/WebDesign/img/icon.jpg'` or relative but need to move up a level with `'../img/icon.jpg'`. IF you are using an absolute path, '/WebDesign/' may not be necessary if thats just the root of your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is head over to an [online sprite generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/) They will generate an image with all of your images together and the CSS needed for the sprites too work. Then you can just add a class onto each list item, and you don't have to load more than one image.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. I changed

```
list-style-image: url("img/icon.png"); }
```

to

```
list-style-image: url("/img/icon.png"); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it on the `li` instead

Comment: its perfectly valid to use it on the ul, too.